# Ionic - show menu icon next to back button

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm having an issue with my navbar side menu icon would disappear or be covered with a back button when I `on-click="goTo"` a page.

How would I display *both*, the menu and back button on these pages?

page.html

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
        <button ion-button menuToggle>
            <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
        </button>
        <ion-title>
            Division
        </ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding id="page">
    <ion-list id="division-list">
        <ion-item color="none" on-click="goToTitle()" id="division-list-item16">
            Division 1 - Government
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item color="none" id="division-list-item">
            Division 2 - Business
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item color="none" id="division-list-item">
            Division 3 - Property; Family
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: I think you'd find the answer for this issue in the referenced post. Please let me know if that solves your issue, of if I misunderstood the question. TLDR: the key is to add the `persistent` attribute equal to true in the menu, like this: `<ion-menu [content]="content" persistent="true">...</ion-menu>`

Comment: @sebaferreras I was looking everywhere for the documentation on this! Thank you sebaferreras!

Comment: Glad to help :)